# Is there a way to know the original URL from the friendly?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Lets say that its been two years (and many people left the company) and we don't know anymore where is the real path of:

```
http://mysubdomain.domain.com/some-friendly-url
```

Is there a way to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the Apache configuration (or .htaccess), **no you don't**. It's totally transparent for the browser.

Some (PHP) websites just do this:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Which means that all the logic is hidden in your web application.